# Finding All of the Possible Dimensions (i.e., the Lengths, Widths, and Heights) of a Rectangular Prism with a Given Surface Area

Tags: geometry, area, volume, surfaces

Here is, in effect, my question: Is there any formulaic/conventional way to go about finding all the possible dimensions of a rectangular prism with only the surface area given?

Below is an example problem:

*What are the possible dimensions of a rectangular prism with a surface area of 24cm^2? Sketch and label.*

Thanks.

Comment: Usually these kinds of questions limit the dimensions to whole numbers, else the domain of possible answers would be infinite. Assuming that much, find $x$, $y$, and $z$ where $2xy+2xz+2yz=24$. With a number as small as 24, you can easily list all the possible values.

Comment: Hmm...what you've suggested seems like a very cumbersome way of going about solving such a seemingly uncomplicated problem. Is there any less time-consuming, more efficient way of solving not just the foregoing example problem, but any other similar problem (i.e., for rectangular prisms with much larger surface area values)?

Comment: Good question. If you have three variables, you need three equations, of course. If I don't have three equations, and I don't want to list by hand all the possibilities, I would write a short computer routine to iterate through all the values of $x, y$ and $z$.